# How to make dropdown animation?

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, styled-components, z-index

I am implementing drop-down list using styled-component in react. In the process, I have two questions.

First, when dropDownVisible changes from true to false, why doesn't the animation effect apply and it disappears immediately? How can I improve the animation effect? Like when this list goes down, I want to make it gradually when it goes up.

Second, when StyledDropdown is dropped down, I want it to drop down behind the StyledHead, so I set the z-index property like that. I want the StyledHead to be always on top, so I'm curious why the StyledHead is hidden as the StyledDropdown drops down, even though I gave the z-index property bigger.

The source code is roughly structured like this:

```
// AApage.jsx

import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { MdArrowDropDown, MdArrowDropUp } from 'react-icons/md';
import styled, { keyframes } from 'styled-components';

const dropAnimation = keyframes`
0% {
  transform : translateY(-300px);
  display : none;
}
100% {
  transform : translateY(0);
}
`;

const StyledHead = styled.div`
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 11;
`;
const StyledDropdown = styled.div`
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  z-index: 3;
  animation: ${dropAnimation} 1s alternate;
`;

const AApage = () => {
  const [dropDownVisible, setDropDownVisible] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const toggleDropDownVisible = () => {
    setDropDownVisible((prev) => !prev);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <StyledHead>
        <div>Dropdown</div>
        <span>{`${dropDownVisible}`}</span>
        {dropDownVisible ? (
          <MdArrowDropUp
            onClick={() => {
              toggleDropDownVisible();
            }}
          ></MdArrowDropUp>
        ) : (
          <MdArrowDropDown
            onClick={() => {
              toggleDropDownVisible();
            }}
          ></MdArrowDropDown>
        )}
      </StyledHead>
      {dropDownVisible ? (
        <StyledDropdown>
          <div>temp data</div>
          <div>temp data</div>
          <div>temp data</div>
        </StyledDropdown>
      ) : (
        <></>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default AApage;
```